# Hide/show multiple graphs in qcustomplot

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

I am making a data logger for a couple of Arduino sensors in Qt. The problem is that I want to log the data in 3 different graphs, each of one having one specific scale, and then I'll choose what graph I will show (just one of the 3 graphs will be displayed at one time).

I tried something like this:

```
QCPGraph *sensorXGraph = ui->graph->addGraph();
QCPGraph *sensorYGraph = ui->graph->addGraph();
sensorXGraph->setVisible(false);
sensorYGraph->setVisible(false);
```

And then, in a slot call from a RadioButton `clicked` event I did:

```
sensorXGraph->setVisible(true);
sensorYGraph->setVisible(false);
```

And the inverse for another RadioButton. But the graph seems to keep the axis of the last graph created. So, if I try to see the `sensorXGraph`, the data will change accordingly but y axis range will be the one of the `sensorYGraph`.

I also tried to make a single QCPAxis for each graph, but it started to be a mess because I had to make QCPAxisRect for each graph as well and the result was worse than the first trial.

How do I achieve to change from one graph to another properly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call clearGraphs() on your QCustomPlot and then add whatever graphs you want to display by calling addGraph() and then call replot() on your QCustomPlot. So it would be something like this:

```
ui->graph->clearGraphs();
ui->graph->addGraph();
// Do whatever you need to do to edit your graph.
ui->graph->replot();
```

Since you are using a radio button I think that it would be easier to draw one graph and add the necessary data and labels based on whatever radio button has been selected. Hopefully that helps!